# ASP.Net VB Separate digit and alphabet

Tags: asp.net

given a string "abc123". How do I separate them and put into a variable? For example abc will stored into a string variable "a" and 123 will stored into an integer variable "b". Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two `StringBuilder`s to accumulate the pieces for the letters and numbers, like this:

```
Dim letters As New StringBuilder()
Dim digits As New StringBuilder()
```

Now loop through the given `String` and determine if the characters is a digit or a letter, adding it to the appropriate `StringBuilder`, like this:

```
Dim theString As String = "abc123"
For Each c As Char In theString
    If Char.IsDigit(c) Then 
        digits.Append(c)
    End If
    If Char.IsLetter(c) Then
        letters.Append(c)
    End If
Next
```

Finally, you can get the `String` representation of each `StringBuilder`, like this:

```
Dim a As String = letters.ToString()
Dim b As String = digits.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str = "abc123"

Dim letters = New [String](str.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray())
Dim digits = Convert.ToInt32(New [String](str.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()))
```

**Note:** I code in c# so i generated this using C# to VB code converter.